# Instagram API: users/self/media/recent API is deprecated so what is the possible alternate to fetch Regular Instagram account recent user posts?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

As per below change log url - `users/self/media/recent` API is deprecated

Reference url is https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

In our application we had used 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN API and it is still working.

For other application I want to get recent post of Regular Instagram account using parameter like:

- MAX_ID   Return media earlier than this max_id.
- MIN_ID   Return media later than this min_id.
- COUNT    Count of media to return.

I tried this existing deprecated API url, it returns recent 20 posts but with `MIN_ID` and `MAX_ID` parameter API is returning recent 20 posts. May it's because API deprecated or my account is in `Sandbox` mode.

So what is the possible alternate to fetch Regular Instagram account's recent user posts?

Answer (score 0):

The `users/self/media/recent` endpoint was not deprecated. The `users/{user_id}/media/recent` endpoint is the one that has been deprecated.

For the 20 post limit, yes, that would be because your account is in Sandbox mode.